# Schematic "store" not found in collection "@schematics/angular"

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data

I install ngrx/store with the following command :

```
ng add @ngrx/store
```

then I want to add store

```
ng generate store auth/Auth --module auth.module.ts
```

get the following error :

> An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "store" not found in
> collection "@schematics/angular". See "xxx\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

Answer (score 13):

Because `ngrx` is not an direct angular schematics. Ngrx is a external library which provide support to add files or create files to your angular project

Your are suppose to generate store file from the ngrx schematics json file, to do that you should run command like below

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store State --root --module app.module.ts
```

If the above command fails you need to run this command

```
npm i @ngrx/schematics -D
```

You can find the detail documentation of its usage here: [@ngrx/schematics](https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics)

Comment: I liked your answer better because doesn't envolve changing the "defaultSchematic". Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 10):

This the last step of the installation.

https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics/install

```
ng add @ngrx/schematics@latest
```

This will update your `angular.json` file this way

```
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  }
```

Now you may re-run the previous schematics

For ex:

```
ng generate store admin/Admin -m admin.module.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same problem.
Installing `@ngrx/schematics` solved it for me:

```
npm install @ngrx/schematics
```